# Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in Xcode iOS

Tags: ios, xcode4, exc-bad-access

I get a error here. Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?
By the way, this is just a learning project for me, so nothing top secret or something. Just trying to make a simple converter.

If the whole project could help: http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?iccgq9iclapado5

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController
@synthesize picker, lngConvertFrom, lngRates;           
@synthesize resultLabel,lngInput;                      
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.lngConvertFrom = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:  <-Thread 1: ExC_bad_Access
```

Comment: The error is on the bottom line.

Comment: You need to more code and explain what you are trying to do. Right now your code you have shown is not even syntactically correct on the line of the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an '@' there. `"LNG HepatittB"` is not an object but a C string.

Comment: Oh, thanks you. I feel silly, i need to look closer for details. BTW; the names are just jokes.

Comment: Oscar I went to tell you the problem - you reversed a '"' and '@' - but you had deleted the question text too quickly. Also, I flaged your 'MF' comment. We have people of both sexes, some youth, and people of many cultures here. Obscenities to not belong on this forum.

Comment: Also, you are not looking at your warnings - there was surely one on this.

Comment: Oh shit, the cybercops are coming. Don't break your back old pal.